# Is there an algebraic way of getting AB = I implies BA = I for finite nxn matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know the proof in terms of linear algebra where you simply argue that if ${AB = I}$ then ${A}$  must be bijective, so since ${B}$ is the inverse map on one side, it must be an inverse on the other side, so ${BA}$ = ${I}$. But I'm interested if there's any way purely going from the identity ${A_{ij}B_{jk}} = {\delta_{ik}}$ to ${{B_{ij}A_{jk}} = \delta_{ik}}$ using algebra and no lifting to a more abstract context. I'm aware of the answers given here: [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i), but all of these use more abstract properties of matrices. These equations so simple it seems like there should be a nice way of proving them without requiring any constructs on top of the basic definitions.

Comment: Since there are algebraic systems in which  a left inverse need not be a right inverse you must necessarily use something from the linear algebra context to prove the theorem.

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm willing to use the algebraic definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @latbbltes, Here is [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3800863/771461). Tell me if you like it.

Comment: In the proposed duplicate question, this answer in particular satisfies your criterion I believe.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3895/18966

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Love it, thank you

Comment: "but all of these use more abstract properties of matrices": no, some were extremely elementary.